# glDrawArrays doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a triangle using `glDrawArrays` function and gl Vertex, Color pointers.

The result is only black empty screen.

```
static const GLfloat vboData[] =
{   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

static const GLfloat colors[]={
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vboData);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Using VBO and VAO also doesn't work.

```
    GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

static const GLfloat vboData[] =
{   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vboData), vboData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but you learn legacy OpenGL. Pick-up a modern OpenGL tutorial -- a one that teaches about Vertex Array Objects, buffers, and the programmable pipeline.

Comment: @ybungalobill previously I used that. I edited my question so you can see the code using VBO and VAO that also doesn't work

Comment: What do you expect to see without any shaders? do you even have a viewport setup?

Comment: @ybungalobill I have viewport set. The tutorial I study made me expect to see white triangle on the black screen, now I know that it is essential to have shader, so thanks for your comment

Comment: Not strictly essential because some implementations indeed provide a default fill-white shader, but that's not necessary so. Another thing: glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer should be right affter glBufferData, and you don't need glDisableVertexAttribArray. Otherwise somebody might mess up with the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding before it's bound to the VAO.

Comment: @Steyrix Your fixed-function version OpenGL code seems fine when I put the appropriate window creation code around it, so perhaps you've forgotten something simple in configuring the window (e.g., requesting a double-buffered window?).  The vertex attrib version would need shader, but the code you show also seems rationale.

Comment: @ybungalobill Perhaps you meant `glBindVertexArray` as compared to `glBufferData`?  The vertex array state set by `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` are associated with the currently bound vertex array (as specified by `glBindVertexArray`).  `glBufferData` merely loads the data into the bound buffer object, but doesn't specify a state binding.

Comment: @radical7: no, I meant exactly what I said. `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is a global state, not a state of a VAO. `glVertexAttribPointer` uses the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` bound at the time of its call to set the buffer reference and the pointer of the VAO. it means that if `glfwWindowShouldClose` binds a different `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (likely it does not, but let's say for the sake of exposition that it does), then `glVertexAttribPointer` will now cause the VAO to reference that buffer rather than the one created by the OP.

Comment: @ybungalobill Sorry, but I think you missed my point: your comment states: _Another thing: glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer should be right affter **glBufferData**_.  I was merely pointing out that restriction is unnecessary.  `glBufferData` allocates the mutable backing-store (i.e., memory) for the bound VBO, but doesn't allocate the VBO (which is likely different object in the context than the memory storing the vertex attribute values)  — that's done with the call to `glBindBuffer` and friends.

Comment: @radical7: Ah, yes. I was just referring to the code in question, specifically to where I would put it with readability considerations in mind. But in general you are right, and I should say that "one shall call `glBindBuffer` just prior to `glVertexAttribPointer`"...

Comment: @radical7, Thank you for your comments, which really clear up some opengl magic for me. I got my code working by adding some shaders.

Comment: @Steyrix you should post your solution as the Answer to this question to help the next person ... and allow us to UP mark your answer ! ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I needed to get my code working is adding shaders to the project.
Here is minimal example.

This is my **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Loader.hpp"
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow *window;


int main(void)
{
//Viewport,window setup using GLFW;

if(!glfwInit()){
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL Triangle", NULL, NULL);

if(!window){
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = true;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

//Loading and compiling shaders;
GLuint shaderID = LoadShader("vertexs.shader", "fragments.shader");

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

static const GLfloat vboData[] =
{   -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vboData), vboData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glUseProgram(shaderID); //Attaching shaders
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
glDeleteProgram(shaderID);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);


glfwTerminate();
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

return 0;
}
```

**Loader.hpp**

```
#ifndef Loader_hpp
#define Loader_hpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLuint LoadShader(const char* vertex_file_path, const char* fragment_file_path);

#endif
```

**Loader.cpp**

```
#include "Loader.hpp"

GLuint LoadShader(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path)
{

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Impossible to open %s. Are you in the right directory ? Don't forget to read the FAQ !\n", vertex_file_path);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;


    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 )
    {
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }



    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 )
    {
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }



    // Link the program
    printf("Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 )
    {
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }


    glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;

}
```

**vertexs.shader** (extension actually doesn't matter)

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main()
{
//We're not modifying positions of vertices
gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

**fragments.shader**

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
void main()
{
color = vec3(1,0,1);
}
```

I also found [these tutorials](http://opengl-tutorial.org) extremely useful to make this solution, so the code above is partially taken from there.